# Background with Webkit

Tags: html, css, dom, animation, webkit

What is the correct code to be able to apply a webkit animation to the entire background image (not the content)?

EX:

```
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(bgsuper.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-name: animate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.333s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
from {
-webkit-transform: ease-in-out(0);
opacity: 0;
}
to {
-webkit-transform: ease-in-out(1);
opacity: 1;
} }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that with CSS, and hence with WebKit animations. CSS can't manipulate background images to that extent, so I think you'll need an alternate solution.

Comment: Hi Blender, thanks for the fast response. I don't see a reason why you can't do it with webkit. Do you have any alternate solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Webkit animations work with CSS properties, and CSS doesn't do this sort of stuff. I'll write one up right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd hack together a pseudo-background:

```
<img id="pseudo-background" src="..." alt="You need me" />
```

It works like a normal background, but doesn't tile. If you need tiling, make a `<div>` with a `background` property and work with that.

**HTML**:

```
<img src="..." id="pseudo-background" alt="foo" />

I work, see!
```

**CSS**:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
from {
-webkit-transform: ease-in-out(0);
opacity: 0;
}
to {
-webkit-transform: ease-in-out(1);
opacity: 1;
} }

#pseudo-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -10;

    -webkit-animation-name: animate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.333s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

}
```

And, a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4z6TS/3/